# How to load images from HDFS into Spark

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-spark

I want to load images from HDFS into spark's RDD.
And then process those images with Spark.

I tested:

```
JavaPairRDD<String, String> pairRdd = jsc.wholeTextFiles("hdfs://cluster-1-m/user/username/images/");
```

to load images from HDFS to Spark's RDD.

Then when I call the imread methods to read the images :

```
Mat image = imread(value._1()); // value is the tuple2<String, String> comming from pairRdd
```

I find that the image is null!

I am using:

- Java
- Spark 2.0.2
- Hadoop 2.7.3

Comment: `imread()` is not part of Spark... is it? all you are using Spark for is reading files from HDFS?

Comment: No it isn't, it's a part of opencv. And as you have said, I use spark to read the images from HDFS

Comment: Okay, then you aren't "using spark" to process images, then, right? So, why do you need Spark exactly?

Comment: I want to use spark to accelerate the image processing (because i have millions of images to process). I want to load the images in the spark' Rdd and then use a map() over the RDD to read thoses images and calculate their features.

Answer (score 0):

The image is null because  `value._1()` is an HDFS path, not a local file that JavaCV expects. The is no "whole file" in HDFS sense because they are broken and distributed into blocks.

You need to download the file off of HDFS before you can process it locally using JavaCV.

Using the native Hadoop API instead of Spark, you can do that.

[Copying file from HDFS to Local Machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11471176/copying-file-from-hdfs-to-local-machine)

Or you can try streaming the content of `value._2()` to a `File` object. (You actually probably want the `binaryFiles(path)` method instead for anything not textual such as images).

In other words, you aren't "using Spark" here other than to scan HDFS directories. The alternative solution is to `map()` over the RDD, package JavaCV into your Spark code via a JAR file, and then you need to download the image to the Spark executor, as mentioned.

Comment: Can you explain to me how to implement the solution with map() and jar file?  JavaPairRDD<String,PortableDataStream> pairRdd = jsc.binaryFiles("hdfs://cluster-1-m/user/username/images/");
JavaRDD<String> rdd = pairRdd.map(new Function<Tuple2<String,PortableDataStream>, String>() {
      @Override
      public String call(Tuple2<String,String> value) {
          // Here : calculate the features image !
      }
    });  How to use that with the imread(path/to/image) method of opencv? 
I admit that I am just a beginner in this domain

Comment: I don't know opencv methods. Your code seems to think it requires a File. You don't need to know Spark to create a new File object and write a String (or a byte array if using binaryFiles)